# How to translate, rotate and scale at a particular point?

Tags: c++, transform, glm-math

I want to translate, rotate and scale, all of these transformations from a specified point(origin). This is what I use right now(I tried many combinations but still cannot figure it out! Looks like it's back to learning Linear Algebra for me).

I am using GLM.

Take a look at the code which I am using:-

```
GLfloat rx = sprite->origin.x / width;
GLfloat ry = sprite->origin.y / height;

translate(model, vec3( -sprite->origin.x, -sprite->origin.y, 0.0f ));
translate(model, vec3( rx * scale[0], ry * scale[1], 0.0f ));
rotate(model, radians(rotation), vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ));
translate(model, vec3( -(rx * scale[0]), -(ry * scale[1]), 0.0f ));
scale(model, vec3( width * scale[0], height * scale[1], 1.0f ));
translate(model, vec3( position[0], position[1], 0.0f ));
```

Origin is the starting point of the object, then translate it to the center for rotation and then translate back.

Scale it and translate the object to the specified position.

I mean, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: why are you translating by the scale factor, instead of scaling by the scale factor? Also, far more important: what do you want to DO? This code does not tell us what your intent is, and your text does not sufficiently explain it. In order to prevent an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can you update your post to explain what you're trying to achieve that you're writing this code for?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I want it to do all the transformations taking the center of the object (let's say sprite). I am implementing a kind of origin in the sprite renderer.

Comment: In that case you already answered your own question: translate(-cx,-cy) so your center is (0,0), then apply your other transforms which will be relative to (0,0), and then translate(cx,cy).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The rotation is the one which is causing the problem. Can you figure out why? This happens with most of the object I am transforming, the objects rotates around the point, not from the center.

Comment: I just told you. Translate by your object's center x/y ((xmin+xmax)/2 by (ymin+ymax)/2), not its offset x/y like your code is doing right now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just posted the answer, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid that that answers makes no sense. 2 and 3 cancel out, so why are they there?  Does something happen between them? If so, why did you leave that out? The _universal_ recipe for rotating an object about its own center is "move the point around which you rotate to be (0,0), rotate it, then move it back", why not follow that recipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,

Do it in this order:-

1. **Translate the object** to the position, e.g, `vec3(position, 0.0f)`.
2. And then **rotate the object**.
3. **Translate the point back to the origin**, e.g, `vec3(-originx * scale, -originy * scale, 0.0f)`.
4. Finally, **scale the object**.

---

##### *Explanation:*

Take the position of the object as `0, 0` in 2D coordinates(*take it as the variable `position` mentioned above in the example of the first point*).

You can see that the object will translate(move) to the position.

> **Note:** Don't forget to multiply it with your scale or it can yield wrong results if your scale is more than **1**.

Now is the time you rotate the object.

Scaling works from the top-left corner so you can't do it from the center.

Next, just scale the object.

That's all.